# How to check the flutter version of a project

Tags: flutter

I have just cloned a Flutter project that was made about 2 years ago. I want to check what version of flutter was used to create this project.
I want to migrate it to the latest version which is 2.2.

Thank you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

- If the project has `pubspec.lock` file, then you can check the version of every package including flutter in it.
- It's optional to mention flutter version in `pubspec.yaml`, so it might or might not be there.
- If the project uses some version manage tool (like fvm), then it would be specified there ( a two year project might not have used it).

I don't think there is another way to check flutter version of a project. You might have to ask the project owner if none of the above solution works.

Comment: upon further review: pubspec.lock = sdks:
  dart: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.12.13+hotfix.5 <2.0.0"                                                                                               pubspec.yaml = environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: Environment sdk in pubspec.yaml is dart version, not flutter version.

Comment: I'm wondering why you need to know the flutter version at the time of creation of this project, to migrate it to lastest one.

Comment: i wanted to know if this was this was made pre 1.12 to follow this guide https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

Comment: also to know if I (when finished) have successfully updated the app by cross checking the versions

Answer (score 12):

```
sdks:
  dart: ">=2.10.2 <2.11.0"
  flutter: ">=1.22.2 <2.0.0"
```

so if dart version is >=2.10.2 <2.11.0 u can use flutter >=1.22.2 <2.0.0

Comment: i just want to add this can found in pubspec.lock. thank you!

Answer (score -1):

write in console:
"flutter --version"

you will see smth like this:

Flutter 3.10.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 682aa387cf (5 months ago) • 2023-06-05 18:04:56 -0500
Engine • revision 2a3401c9bb
Tools • Dart 3.0.3 • DevTools 2.23.1

Answer (score -2):

To check the Flutter version used in a Flutter project, you can follow these steps:

Navigate to the root directory of your Flutter project in the terminal or command prompt.

Run the following command:

flutter --version
(This command will display the Flutter version along with Dart and other related information.)

If you want to check the Flutter channel (e.g., stable, beta, dev), you can also run:

flutter channel
(This will show the current Flutter channel.)

Additionally, you can check the pubspec.yaml file in the root directory of your Flutter project. Look for the flutter section, which includes the SDK version used in the project. For example:

environment:
sdk: ">=2.0.0 <3.0.0"
(This indicates that the project is compatible with Flutter SDK version 2.0.0 or higher, but less than 3.0.0.)

To migrate your project to the latest version of Flutter, you can use the following commands:

flutter upgrade
flutter pub upgrade
(These commands will upgrade your Flutter SDK and the project dependencies to the latest versions. After upgrading, you may need to check for any breaking changes in the Flutter release notes and update your code accordingly.)