# How to check which version was used for Flutter and Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to fix some bugs in old Flutter app, but I get some errors due to the old version of flutter used by the project.
How to check which version of flutter and dart was used to get rid of the errors?
and then downgrade to such versions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68230577/13558035

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check the flutter version of a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68229672/how-to-check-the-flutter-version-of-a-project)

Answer (score 0):

You can run the flutter project with specified versions by changing the environment settings in `pubspec.yaml` file,

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
```

to build app with `null-safety` enabled you can use `">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`. you have to specify which version you want here. This environment setting decides which flutter version is used to build the project.